# What does the dot sign mean in the command

Tags: linux

I am not very familiar with all Linux command line stuff. I need to find all the files with a suffix '.fvp' under a directory and all its sub-directories. I got it online, it works perfectly fine. But I didn't quite understand what it really means.
The command line is as follows:

```
ls -R | grep '.*[.]fvp'
```

I know the -R option is for listing recursively and the pipe is for redirecting. Then why in the single quote, there is a dot before the asterisk and another dot within the brace. And whey not just '*.fvp'?

Thank you!

Comment: `[.]` is a cheap way of saying "literal period", because otherwise `.` would treated as a regex metachar for "any one single character". `\.` would serve just as well.

Answer (score 0):

@Grep uses regular expression (regex) syntax as opposes to glob syntax that you may be used to.  `*.fvp` is the glob expression for what you are trying to do, but with regexes, it is slightly different.

`.` in a regex matches any single character.  `*` means any amount of the preceding character.  So, `.*` means any character zero or more times.  `[.]` means, as Marc B said, a literal period, because `.` already means something else.